# Extending Custom Compound View

Tags: android

I plan on creating an expandable, compound view that is composed of a header layout and a content layout; in other words, both the header and the content sections are some layout (e.g. relative layout). Upon clicking the header, the content layout will become visible.

The issue I have is understanding how one can generalize this base compound view so that I can extend such and setup the contents within both the header and content layout within a separate extending xml file.

**Base Compound View**
[image]

**Example of Extending Compound View**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to either use ViewStubs and inflate new views into them, or use fragments and place fragments in them.